# Prove E[x] is the integral of T(x) from 0 to x, where T(x) is the tail distribution function of x

Tags: integration

x is a continuous and nonnegative random variable with cdf F and density f ,prove expectation E[x] is the integral of T(x) from 0 to x, where T(x) is the tail distribution function of x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal F,P)$. By Fubini's Theorem we get $\int_0^{\infty} P\{ X>t\}\, dt =\int_0^{\infty} \int I_{\{ X>t\}}\, dP \, dt=\int_0^{\infty} \int I_{\{ t<X\}}\, dt \, dP= \int X dP =EX$.